# Class App\Http\UserMiddleware does not exist

Tags: laravel

Class App\Http\UserMiddleware does not exist

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;



use Closure;
Use Auth;

class UserMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

 public function handle($request, Closure $next)

 {

     if(auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 2){

         return $next($request);

     }
  else {

         return redirect()->route('login');

     }
 }
}
```

Comment: run cmd composer dump-autoload

Comment: Add middleware to `kernel.php` in `App\Http` folder.

Comment: Your namespace don't match. According to the error message your files is placed in `App\Http` but namespace is `App\Http\Middleware`.

Comment: u might `use App\Http\Middleware\UserMiddleware;` instead of `use App\Http\UserMiddleware`

Answer (score 1):

If the file is saved in App\Http and not App\Http\Middleware then your namespace declaration is wrong and will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**

```
 use App\Http\Middleware\UserMiddleware;
```

Answer (score 0):

change your middleware in your kernel file to something like this

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'name_of_your_middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\UserMiddleware',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. I realised I have added `App\Http\Middleware\RequestLogger::class` but I was missing `\` at the beginning.

So, finally I added `\App\Http\Middleware\RequestLogger::class`, and it was working